# LINQPad Dump using Util.Run

Tags: linqpad

I have a LINQ script that runs in a loop for a long time, over many records, and dumps the records it processed at the end of each iteration.  So I see a dump of records as the script is running.

```
    foreach (string record in lotsOfRecords) {
       // do stuff ...
       record.Dump()
    }
```

When I run this from another script using Util.Compile, Util.run, I don't see the output from the results window as the application is running.  But I can tell the script is running by seeing the database changes it is causing.

```
    using (var query = Util.Compile (myQueryPath))
    {
        query.Run (QueryResultFormat.HtmlFragment).AsString().Dump(); // no results
    }
```

I've tried Text, HTML and HTML fragment and I don't see any output while the script is running.  I'm running LINQPad 5.43 (Pro)

Comment: _I don't see any output **while** the script is running_   - I would not expect to see anything until the script had completed and then you would get the raw html.

Comment: `Util.Run` returns any `Dump` output from the script based on the `QueryResultFormat` once the script returns.